# Optirun uses Nvidia, Primusrun uses Intel card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, steam

I want to run games on Ubuntu with Steam. I installed Bumblebee and Primus and the default nVidia driver(304). I've read that the 310 driver gives a huge performance boost so I wanted to try that. I installed the nvidia-experimental-310 & nvidia-settings-310 and configured [bumblebee.conf](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/use-nvidia-experimental-drivers-310.html) On the bottom he points out that I have to edit */usr/bin/primusrun* to use nvidia-experimental-310

```
#!/bin/bash

# Readback-display synchronization method
# 0: no sync, 1: D lags behind one frame, 2: fully synced
# export PRIMUS_SYNC=${PRIMUS_SYNC:-0}

# Verbosity level
# 0: only errors, 1: warnings (default), 2: profiling
export PRIMUS_VERBOSE=${PRIMUS_VERBOSE:-2}

# Secondary display
# export PRIMUS_DISPLAY=${PRIMUS_DISPLAY:-:8}

# "Accelerating" libGL
# $LIB will be interpreted by the dynamic linker
export PRIMUS_libGLa=${PRIMUS_libGLa:-'/usr/lib/nvidia-310-updates/libGL.so.1:/usr/lib32/nvidia-310-updates/libGL.so.1'}

# "Displaying" libGL
# export PRIMUS_libGLd=${PRIMUS_libGLd:-'/usr/lib/$LIB/mesa/libGL.so.1'}

# Directory containing primus libGL
PRIMUS_libGL=${PRIMUS_libGL:-/usr/lib/'$LIB'/primus}

# On some distributions, e.g. on Gentoo, libnvidia-tls.so is not available
# in default search paths.  Add its path manually after the primus library
case $PRIMUS_libGLa in
/usr/lib*/nvidia-310-updates*|'') # nvidia is used by default
 PRIMUS_libGL=${PRIMUS_libGL}:${PRIMUS_libGLa///libGL.so.1}
;; esac

# Mesa drivers need a few symbols to be visible
# export PRIMUS_LOAD_GLOBAL=${PRIMUS_LOAD_GLOBAL:-'libglapi.so.0'}

# Need functions from primus libGL to take precedence
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PRIMUS_libGL}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

# And go!
exec "$@"
```

My system

```
Lenovo ideapad Y580
Ubuntu 13.04
Intel Core i7
nVidia GTX660M
```

When I run *optirun glxspheres* I get this output:

```
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GTX 660M/PCIe/SSE2
150.527939 frames/sec - 167.989179 Mpixels/sec
```

When I run vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus glxspheres I get

```
292.591142 frames/sec - 326.531714 Mpixels/sec
```

with my nvdia

However when I run *primusrun glxspheres* I get

```
Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x20
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
Context is Indirect
OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
63.910723 frames/sec - 71.324367 Mpixels/sec
```

I also tried to set vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus %command% in the Steam which doesn't open any game (TF2 & Trine 2). The article says I should update the primusrun to use nvidia-experimental-310 but I replaced it with nvidia-310-updates because those are the folders which exist.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am in exactly the same boat.

Comment: Posted an answer

Comment: @glenatron What I did is, I purged everything related to bumblebee and reinstalled it. I'm using the nvidia-331 driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I never fixed it and I didn't `primusrun` to use the Nvidia card. However it's not necessary to use the `primusrun` launcher binary.

I now run my games from Steam with

```
optirun -b primus %command%
```

in the `LAUNCH OPTIONS`

If you want to run Big Picture on your Nvidia card you can do that:
http://bartinger.at/run-steam-big-picture-on-an-optimus-card/

```
optirun -b primus steam -bigpicture
```

From the command line

Edit: I'm using the nvidia-331 driver.
My [bumblebee config on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/p0yCpDyS). I hope it helps someone.